# Add progress dialog in center of activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-progressbar

I am not able to add progressbar as my need as given below can anyone help me

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:background="#039BE5">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mobileRelView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:padding="2dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mobile_Image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="1dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/mobile1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mobile_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="#a4000000"
            android:onClick="goToMobileForm"
            android:text="MOBILE"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/laptop_Image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/laptopservicing" />

        <Button
            android:text="LAPTOP"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/laptop_button"
            android:onClick="goToLaptopForm"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:background="#a4000000"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/desktop_Image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/otherservice" />

        <Button
            android:text="DESKTOP"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/desktop_button"
            android:onClick="goToDesktopForm"
            android:background="#a4000000"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/others_Image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/otherservice" />

        <Button
            android:text="OTHERS"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/others_button"
            android:onClick="gotToOthersForm"
            android:background="#A4000000"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I need to this progressbar to my activity

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

When i simple add it i get this output

[image]

But i need it overly in the middle  like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

to programetically show the `ProgressDialog` at Center

```
 ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Title", "Message");
 dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

To  center the `Indicator`

use a custom layout containing your `progressBar`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

use it using:

```
progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_layout);  //just the indicator at center
```

To initilize Progressdialog.

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);//initialization;
```

to setMessage:

```
dialog.setMessage("Message");
```

if u do not want to display the message:

```
dialog.setMessage(null);
dialog.show();
```

to make background transperant:

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: but my dialog will get left aligned even though no text given to it i think that is vacant space for title can i eliminate it /

Comment: now its in the center but a white small rectangular bar is there

Comment: its small in size but nice width

Comment: use: `progressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);`

Comment: ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,null,null);             can you remove this show from here because i need it only in some places to show if{ // here i need to display onle circle} else {// here i need to display with title}

Comment: you can ,make the `progressDialog` global and call `show` with different parameters based on your condition.....also you can call `progressDialog.dismiss();` to stop the progressdialog.in previous condition

Comment: i am asking that can you initialize this progress dialog without show

Comment: okay...`ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);//initialization;
        dialog.show();`

Comment: where should i give null parameter

Comment: its again white bar as first

Comment: sir this i know this way the way of my code                                                  dialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);  dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setMessage(null);
                dialog.setTitle(null);
                dialog.show();                                                 but still now this circle is in left side

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138564/discussion-between-rafsanahmad007-and-arun-mohan).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the root `LinearLayout` using a `FrameLayout`, add your `ProgressBar` as the second child. It will be shown above everything else.

Comment: But may i ask you, now there are 5 layouts already if i add again it will cause may app to get slower ?

Comment: Nesting several views will slow your app, yes. But that means around 4-5 levels of nesting and lots of views.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch your `LinearLayout` to a `RelativeLayout` as your first layout in the xml.

Then you can do:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"
    android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

and the progress will stay centered

Comment: no i have already tried it but at that time it will be centered and only the last relative view is visible

Comment: that's because you need to add a reference with android_layoutBelow="the id of the relativelayout above" to every RelativeLayout to let them stay vertically